# Jquery mobile Ajax call

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, json

I'm developing an application using Phongap framework. I made the Ajax call for a local PHP file, it works perfectly on a PC but on android platform it displays the source code of the PHP file. So, is there any solution to parse the code instead of showing just the code, the same way as on PC?

PHP source code(Test.php)

```
<?php
$x = "This text From PHP file 2";
echo json_encode($x);
?>

and this is the ajax call

    $.ajax
                (
                    {
                        url: "Test.php",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function(data,status,jqXHR)
                        {
                        alert(data+"And "+status);
                        $('#showdata').text(data+" And "+status);
                        }
                    }
                );
```

Comment: i think you need to include it in your file header 
header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: If it shows just the source code, it means that PHP server is not running. PHP files need to be executed with PHP or PHP-CLI binary in most cases.

Comment: Hi Jompper, The PHP server is working the PC. The PHP is a local file in the android device.